# Xen and Turbo Boost

Tags: linux, debian, virtualization, xen

Running the Debian Squeeze default Xen, I am unable to get any of the CPU frequency scaling stuff going.

As soon as I revert to the standard kernel I get it.

Digging through the internet it seems that Xen got a few patches in [2010](http://old-list-archives.xen.org/archives/html/xen-devel/2010-03/msg01542.html) my only guess is that they did not find their way into Debian yet.

Is there a way to get Turbo Boost going in debian Xen, is this in backports?

Are there any other distros out there that have cpufreq / turbo boost enabled for the Xen kernel?

Comment: What is the xen version? The hypervisor has to support this as well as the Dom0.